# print screen doesn't work if VirtualBox is active window

Tags: virtualbox, print-screen

My host system is Windows Vista home premium. I have setup a VBox environment to install slackware Linux, I'm trying to take screen prints of the various stages, but I can't seem to get the print screen to work

pressing the print-screen button on my keyboard sends a * into the guest system (I see it appear on the Linux command prompt)

Alt print screen does nothing

Print screen using the on-screen keyboard doesn't capture anything

I've downloaded [ScreenPrint32](http://download.cnet.com/Screen-Print-Capture-32/3000-2384_4-10135610.HTML), a utility for screen shots, but that fails to work at all.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Print screen and Virtual Box can be a little quirky sometimes. I get around this by using the snipping tool. If you click the Start Orb and begin typing 'snip' it should pop up. (I like it better than screen a straight print screen anyway since I discovered it)

Comment: Mark, I didn't know about that snippet tool, but it works great. Many thanks :)

Comment: Is there something like this in XP? I have a virtual PC loaded with XP and I can only use PrintScreen to capture the entire screen. I need a way to capture only the active window.

Comment: If you are using a winXP guest on a win7 host, you can still use the win7 snip tool, just have it highlight inside of the non-maximized vbox window

Answer (score 5):

Disable "Auto capture keyboard" from virtualbox preferences.

Main virtualbox window (not running guests) -> File -> Preferences -> Input -> Unselect "Auto capture keyboard"

Answer (score 0):

VMware workstation 6.5.4 running on rhel with guest OS of Windows XP.

From menu `view -> gt -> grab input`, then press:

<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>prnt scrn</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>prnt scrn</kbd> as per normal in Windows XP. Then paste in guest as normal.

No extra software required.